# Use Atmosphere or Cometd

Tags: java, comet, atmosphere

What are the differences between these two Java comet libraries? Is there a reason to pick one over the other?

Answer (score 1):

From my personal experiences, i higly suggest you to get away from both of them! DWR team turned back to start development and version 3.0 will be ready soon.

Comment: Could you give reasons why I should "get away" from them? What problems did you have with Atmosphere or Cometd that DWR solved?

Comment: You have to manage many things with others. in other words, you have to implement your own client side solution and a proper serializer. DWR got them all.

Comment: DWR looks ... well not really active: http://dwr.2114559.n2.nabble.com/Is-DWR-still-alive-td7579778.html I would choose the other alternatives (e.g. I've chosen cometd and it was a no brainer to get startet as the docs are really good). also the statement "3.0 will be ready soon" is now nearly 2 years old ;)

Answer (score 1):

From my own experience working with the Atmosphere framework it has some lack of documentation and issues too, like having to add your own functionality to the actual protocol. It is fairly recent and it seems to be gaining more traction and support but it (still) doesn't have a huge community behind it. Other than that it has both server and clients in Java and JavaScript. It's integrated in Vaadin framework and there are already many examples of use with other frameworks like Play and GWT. A very good thing about Atmosphere is that it virtually supports any container: Tomcat, JBoss, Jetty, Glassfish...so if this is a requirement it's a great choice.

Cometd I don't know from experience but what I know from looking around is that it seems to be very well documented. The GH repository doesn't have as many followers as Atmosphere though. From what I know it doesn't support as many containers as Atmosphere.

Both integrate with Google Guice and other common requirements.

You can also find an old article on this question here, but both frameworks evolved a lot since then:

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/wa-reverseajax4/